# skypeforlinux won't work anymore on Debian

Tags: skype

It happens again :(

After a reboot, skypeforlinux does not work any more on my bookworm (testing) Debian installation. It starts, goes through authentication, then stops there with a blank window. Calling it on the command line shows no messages or errors.

I tried with the latest 8.79.76.22 version and with the oldest 8.74.0.152 version on the repo, no change.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the same when updating Fedora. It seems to be a bug with skype or with the electron/chromium it runs in. Microsoft for some reason manages to build the only so highly non-portable electron apps I'm aware of.

Anyway, what worked for me is using the skype flatpak (for whichever reason, just adding another layer of container around electron, which is a full browser plus all libraries just to run the javascript skype app, helps. Modern GUI application development never ceases to amaze me.):

```bsh
sudo apt install flatpak
sudo flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
sudo flatpak install flathub com.skype.Client
```

so that you can finally

```bsh
flatpak run com.skype.Client
```

Comment: Wonderful, it works, thanks. Only thing, the window title is "Skype (as superuser)", but it correctly looks in my user ~/.config/skyperforlinux to get the configuration. Any idea why the strange title?